# Do I need to create an assocation table for a :has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to use a `:has_many :through` type association, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: work_units.developer_id:
```

Many other posts about this sort of thing have just had spelling mistakes, but I've checked mine.

```
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :skype_name, :language_ids, :user_attributes

  has_many :work_units
  has_many :projects, :through => :work_units
  ...
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :complete, :description, :finalised, :price

  has_many :work_units
  has_many :developers, :through => :work_units
  ...
end

class WorkUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hours_worked

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :developer
end
```

I've run `db:migrate` and it didn't complain. I did make a mistake and had to rollback the db then re-migrate, but I think I did it right. I use the `annotate` gem and it doesn't show any of the relationship ids I'd expect. So, do I need to create a WorkUnits table or am I missing something? The rails guide didn't mention manually making tables.

**Edit**

Here's the migration I used to create the WorkUnit model and stuff:

```
class CreateWorkUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :work_units do |t|
      t.integer :hours_worked, :default => 0
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit 2**

Snippets from my schema.rb:

```
create_table "work_units", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "hours_worked", :default => 0
  t.datetime "created_at",                  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                  :null => false
end

create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.decimal  "price",       :precision => 8, :scale => 2
  t.boolean  "complete",    :default => false
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end
```

Similarly for `:developers`. So, why doesn't my migration add the association information for me?

Comment: To rerun annotate: `bundle exec annotate`. You might need to restart your development server to pick up the database changes.

Comment: For your `has_many :through` relationship only a table for the `WorkUnit` class has to exist with `project_id` and `developer_id` integer columns. You can check your `db/schema.rb` whether it is currently defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the foreign keys to your `work_units` table.

```
class CreateWorkUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :work_units do |t|
      t.integer :hours_worked, :default => 0
      t.integer :project_id, null: false
      t.integer :developer_id, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :work_units, :project_id
    add_index :work_units, :developer_id
  end
end
```

Another way:

```
class CreateWorkUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :work_units do |t|
      t.integer :hours_worked, :default => 0
      t.belongs_to :project
      t.belongs_to :developer
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :work_units, :project_id
    add_index :work_units, :developer_id
  end
end
```

You can also define these fields when generating your model, then they'll be added to the migration automatically as show in the second snippet.

```
$ rails g model WorkUnit hours_worked:integer project:belongs_to developer:belongs_to
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your WorkUnit migration should look like this:

```
class CreateWorkUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :work_units do |t|
      t.integer :hours_worked, :default => 0
      t.references :developer
      t.references :project
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :work_units, :developer_id
    add_index :work_units, :project_id
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Everyone answered so quickly, I don't know who was first. Sorry I didn't give you the points this time

Comment: for interest's sake, why would you use `t.references` rather than `t.belongs_to` or `t.integer` in @Thomas`s answer? Is there any difference?

Comment: From the guides: *Using t.integer :supplier_id makes the foreign key naming obvious and explicit. In current versions of Rails, you can abstract away this implementation detail by using t.references :supplier instead.* and *Another helper is called references (also available as belongs_to). In its simplest form it just adds some readability.*

Answer (score 0):

A table for `WorkUnit` needs to exist, whether that means it migration was automatically generated via scaffolding or if the migration was manually written by you.

If you don't have a migration yet that creates that table, you'll need to create that migration because the table does need to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You do need a work_units table with a project_id and developer_id column.

Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/activerecord_datenbank_anlegen.html if you don't know how to create a table.